# Page becomes white after my component is added

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-bootstrap. I'm trying to display a list of cards. The list size can vary. But entire page becomes white after the component' Websites' is added at the bottom of 'Dashboard Page'. `{this.state.page === 'websites' ? this.websites : null}`

**Websites Component**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './Websites.css'

export default class Websites extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.websites = []
    this.getWebsites()
  }

  getWebsites () {
    // TODO: Need Implementation
    var websites = this.makeTestWebsites()
    for (var i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
      this.websites.push(
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.SubTitle>{websites[i].domain}</Card.SubTitle>
            <Card.Title>{websites[i].name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.SubTitle>{websites[i].websiteClass}</Card.SubTitle>
            <Card.SubTitle>{websites[i].created}</Card.SubTitle>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      )
    }
  }

  makeTestWebsites () {
    return [
      {
        name: 'test domain',
        domain: 'domain.com',
        websiteClass: 'starter',
        created: '2077-12-05'
      },
      {
        name: 'hello domain',
        domain: 'chicken.org',
        websiteClass: 'premium',
        created: '1996-02-12'
      }
    ]
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.websites}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

is called from **DashboardPage**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './dashboardStyle.css'
import Websites from './Websites'

export default class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      page: 'websites'
    }
    this.websites = <Websites />
    this.switchToWebsites()
  }

  switchToWebsites () {
    this.setState({ page: 'websites' })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='sidemenu'>
          <Button variant='primary' className='sidenav-button'>
            <img
              alt=''
              src='/logo/xxxLogo.png'
              width='30'
              height='30'
              className='sidenav-button-icon'
              onClick={this.showLandingPage}
            />
            Websites
          </Button>
          <Button variant='primary' className='sidenav-button'>
            <img
              alt=''
              src='/logo/xxxLogo.png'
              width='30'
              height='30'
              className='sidenav-button-icon'
              onClick={this.showLandingPage}
            />
            Email
          </Button>
          <Button variant='primary' className='sidenav-button'>
            <img
              alt=''
              src='/logo/xxxLogo.png'
              width='30'
              height='30'
              className='sidenav-button-icon'
              onClick={this.showLandingPage}
            />
            How To Use
          </Button>
          <Button variant='primary' className='sidenav-button'>
            <img
              alt=''
              src='/logo/xxxLogo.png'
              width='30'
              height='30'
              className='sidenav-button-icon'
              onClick={this.showLandingPage}
            />
            Support
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div className='right-menu'>
          {this.state.page === 'websites' ? this.websites : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Sorry for little details. I'm new and don't know what info you need. If you need any details please comment. Thank you.

**Edit: Error log from console**

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Comment: You probably have an error somewhere, and no ErrorBoundaries (so your component tree is removed from the DOM).

Look in the browser's console log and report the error in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

#### Websites Component

```js
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Websites.css";

const testWebsites = [
  {
    name: "test domain",
    domain: "domain.com",
    websiteClass: "starter",
    created: "2077-12-05"
  },
  {
    name: "hello domain",
    domain: "chicken.org",
    websiteClass: "premium",
    created: "1996-02-12"
  }
];

export default class Websites extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // TODO: Need Implementation
    this.state = {
      websites: testWebsites
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.websites.map(website => (
          <Card key={website.name}>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.SubTitle>{website.domain}</Card.SubTitle>
              <Card.Title>{website.name}</Card.Title>
              <Card.SubTitle>{website.websiteClass}</Card.SubTitle>
              <Card.SubTitle>{website.created}</Card.SubTitle>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Dashboard Component

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./dashboardStyle.css";
import Websites from "./Websites";

export default class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      page: "websites"
    };
  }

  showLandingPage = () => {
    this.setState({
      page: "landing"
    });
  };

  showWebsitesPage = () => {
    this.setState({
      page: "websites"
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="sidemenu">
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            className="sidenav-button"
            onClick={this.showLandingPage}
          >
            <img
              alt=""
              src="/logo/BornBee Logo.png"
              width="30"
              height="30"
              className="sidenav-button-icon"
            />
            Websites
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            className="sidenav-button"
            onClick={this.showLandingPage}
          >
            <img
              alt=""
              src="/logo/BornBee Logo.png"
              width="30"
              height="30"
              className="sidenav-button-icon"
            />
            Email
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            className="sidenav-button"
            onClick={this.showLandingPage}
          >
            <img
              alt=""
              src="/logo/BornBee Logo.png"
              width="30"
              height="30"
              className="sidenav-button-icon"
            />
            How To Use
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            className="sidenav-button"
            onClick={this.showLandingPage}
          >
            <img
              alt=""
              src="/logo/BornBee Logo.png"
              width="30"
              height="30"
              className="sidenav-button-icon"
            />
            Support
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div className="right-menu">
          {this.state.page === "websites" ? <Websites /> : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

I made a few notable changes to your code.

**Websites**

1. Move your test data outside of the component
2. Use `this.state` instead of class properties
3. `map` over the data array. **Note:** the `key` prop must be unique ([source](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys))
4. Change your React import. I'm not sure if the wildcard import was a bug, but I've never seen it done like that.

**Dashboard**

1. **Don't call `setState` in the constructor** ([source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor))
2. Don't store your component in a property variable
3. I moved your `onClick` to the `<Button>` component because that makes more sense to me. But, you can move it back to the `img` if you prefer or need it there.
4. Made your class methods arrow functions to bind `this`

One last thing I'd suggest is that, instead of manually handling the page routing like you're doing, perhaps use [`React Router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).